# How to save Shapely geometry into a file and load it later into a variable

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely

How to save `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon` object into a file (especially to a shapefile) and load it later into the Python environment when it is needed?

```
from shapely import geometry
q = [(82,32.261),(79.304,32.474),(77.282,30.261),(81.037,28.354)]
polygon = geometry.Polygon(q)
```

I want to save `polygon` object to a shapefile (or any other formatted file) and want to load it later when it is needed.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate (at least for writing, not sure about reading): [How to write Shapely geometries to shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/52705/142375)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to the party. But this is how I like to do it, nice and simple with pickle.

```
from shapely import geometry
import pickle

# Make a polygon
q = [(82,32.261),(79.304,32.474),(77.282,30.261),(81.037,28.354)]
polygon = geometry.Polygon(q)

# Check it out
print('My new polygon: \n', polygon)


# Save polygon to disc
with open('./my_polygon', "wb") as poly_file:
    pickle.dump(polygon, poly_file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# Load polygon from disc
with open('./my_polygon', "rb") as poly_file:
    loaded_polygon = pickle.load(poly_file)

# Check it out again
print('My loaded polygon: \n', loaded_polygon)
```

OUT:

```
My new polygon: 
 POLYGON ((82 32.261, 79.304 32.474, 77.282 30.261, 81.03700000000001 28.354, 82 32.261))
My loaded polygon: 
 POLYGON ((82 32.261, 79.304 32.474, 77.282 30.261, 81.03700000000001 28.354, 82 32.261))
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the geojson format, using [`shapely.to_geojson`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.to_geojson.html) and [`shapely.from_geojson`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.from_geojson.html).

Advantages are that the file is human-readable and more shareable since it is not recommended to share pickle files across devices.

```py
from shapely import Polygon, to_geojson, from_geojson
from pathlib import Path

filepath = Path("polygon.geojson")
polygon = Polygon([(82, 32), (79, 32), (77, 30), (81, 28)])

# To GeoJSON
filepath.write_text(to_geojson(polygon))

# From GeoJSON
polygon_read = from_geojson(filepath.read_text())

# Check they are the same
print(filepath.read_text())
print(polygon)
print(polygon_read)
assert polygon == polygon_read
```

```py
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[82.0,32.0],[79.0,32.0],[77.0,30.0],[81.0,28.0],[82.0,32.0]]]}
POLYGON ((82 32, 79 32, 77 30, 81 28, 82 32))
POLYGON ((82 32, 79 32, 77 30, 81 28, 82 32))
```